# Cordova Android Release build not working

Tags: android, cordova

I am getting issue in building release apk using cordova build. Debug apk is working fine, but release apk is not working.
command used for build:
cordova build android --release

Comment: Did u sign the release build with signing key..??

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your release by signing, 
`cordova run android --release -- --keystore=../my-release-key.keystore --storePassword=password --alias=alias_name --password=password`
Alternatively, you could specify them in a build configuration file (`build.json`) using the `--buildConfig` argument to the same commands. Here's a sample of a build configuration file:

```
{
    "android": {
        "debug": {
            "keystore": "../android.keystore",
            "storePassword": "android",
            "alias": "heroguideapp",
            "password" : "St1lL4N4Vi",
            "keystoreType": ""
        },
        "release": {
            "keystore": "../android.keystore",
            "storePassword": "",
            "alias": "heroguideapp",
            "password" : "St1lL4N4Vi",
            "keystoreType": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have signed apk. but still its not working. Any idea how we can add ssl certificate for apk

Comment: any luck solving this problem. I am stuck with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I had issues building my app in release and i solved it like this:

1. Make sure you have a valid keystore. I followed loosely [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/publishing/publish-to-a-store?view=toolsforcordova-2017) guide.
2. I created a build.json file which contains only the release keystore:

   ```
   {

    "android": {
        "release": {
            "keystore": "C:\\Your\\Path\\Here\\CordovaAndroid.keystore",
            "storePassword": "YourPassword",
            "alias": "CordovaAndroid",
            "password": "YourPassword",
            "keystoreType": ""
        }
    }
   }
   ```

The build.json should be located in the same directory where config.xml is located.

3. run `cordova build android --release --buildConfig=build.json`